# how to make message be half half to avoid message length error?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

when I have like 25+ bots in my server bot can't send the message according to message send length ability, so is there any way like to make if the length 2000 send another message with bots list

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === "-allbots") { 
    if(!message.channel.guild) return;
  let addone = 1;
const botcounts = message.guild.members.filter(m=>m.user.bot).map(m=>`\`\`${addone++}\`\` - <@${m.id}>`);
            message.channel.send(`**I Found ${message.guild.members.filter(m=>m.user.bot).size} bots ${botcounts.join('\n')}**`)

      .catch(err => {
            message.reply('message is more than 2000 charachter');
            console.error(err);
            })
          }
      })
```

Comment: Can you add few more lines to explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js can automatically do it for you. Pass in a [MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) object in [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) utilizing the `split` property.

```js
message.channel.send('Text longer than 2000 characters...', {
  split: {
    prepend: '...',
    append: '...'
  }
);
```

The messages would appear like this:

> ```
> first part...
> ```
>
> ```
> ...second part
> ```

---

**Edit:**

Incorporating this into your existing code would look like similar to this:

```js
message.channel.send(
  `**I found ${botcounts.length} bot${botcounts.length !== 1 ? 's' : ''}.**
  ${botcounts.join('\n')}`,

  { split: true } // No "..." is added. See above for that usage. 
)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: can you add this to my code, or like be more obvious with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like

```
messagesArray = []

if (message.length >= 2000) {
  let cutMessages = []

  // Here you have cut your messages
  //if they can pass 4k chars, you'll need a loop, if not, just use substr

  messagesArray.push(cutMessages)
}

if (messagesArray.length) 
  messagesArray.forEach( message => { console.log(message) })
else console.log(message)
```